# How do webfonts that don't contain certain chars behave?

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I have a webfont that doesn't support Cyrillic. The font only has latin chars. If I try and display some Cyrillic chars, instead of displaying blank or corrupt chars (as I would expect it) it bypasses the webfont and displays them in a system font instead. Whilst this is a good thing I don't know why or how. As I understand it, if a font specified in the CSS isn't supported by a browser or the browser doesn't support webfonts it is then that a substitute font is put in place. However this is happening if the characters used aren't supported. Is my understanding of this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers do missing character fallback by default, so you never see blank characters when something's missing. If the developer uses a font family stack like `font-family: MyCyrillicFont, Arial, sans-serif` your browser will use the next available font. Otherwise, the browser itself has a default font setting (that the user can typically choose).

In short, browsers have fallbacks on the characters level.

Answer (score 2):

it can be difficult when using a font that is not supported in your language.
It varies from font to font and browser to browser.
So there is no hard and fast rule sorry.

I would recommend making sure you HTML is set to support Unicode fonts.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I would also programme your font so it is in a stack,(has a default to full back on if unsupported)
And give it and test in all browsers to see if it defaults or doesn't show.
You may wish to find a font that is suited to that language.